# Should I always close stdout explicitly?

Tags: python, c++, windows, pipe, subprocess

I am trying to integrate a small Win32 C++ program which reads from stdin and writes the decoded result (˜128 kbytes)to the output stream.

I read entire input into buffer with

```
while (std::cin.get(c)) { }
```

After I write entire output to the stdout.

Everything works fine when I run the application from command line eg `test.exe < input.bin > output.bin`, however this small app is supposed to be run from Python.

I expect that Python `subprocess.communicate` is supposed to be used, the docs say:

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and
>   stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.

So `communicate()` will wait until the end-of-file before waiting my app to finish - is EOF supposed to happen when my application exits? Or should I explicitly do fclose(stderr) and fclose(stdout)?

Comment: You should never explicitly release any resource you did not explicitly acquire unless you have specific documentation that tells you otherwise. Failure to adhere to this is a recipe for difficult to solve problems.

Comment: Now  I see the point - the child process gets its own handle/descriptor for the other end of the pipe which is closed at least when the subprocess is terminated.

Comment: unrelated: to emulate `test.exe < input.bin > output.bin` shell command, you could use `subprocess.check_call('test', stdin=open('input.bin'), stdout=open('stdout.bin', 'w'))` i.e., you don't need `.communicate()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Don't close stdout**

In the general case, it is actually wrong, since it is possible to register a function with [`atexit()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit/) which tries to write to stdout, and this will break if stdout is closed.

When the process terminates, all handles are closed by the operating system automatically.  This includes stdout, so you are not responsible for closing it manually.

(Technically, the C++ runtime will [normally](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/) try to flush and close all C++ streams before the OS even has a chance to get involved, but the OS absolutely *must* close any handles which the runtime, for [whatever](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/quick_exit/) [reason](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/terminate/), misses.)

In specialized circumstances, it may be useful to close standard streams (for example, when daemonizing), but it should be done with great care.  It's usually a good idea to redirect to or from the null device (`/dev/null` on Unix, `nul` on Windows) so that code expecting to interact with those streams will still work.  On Unix, this is done with [`freopen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen); Windows has [an equivalent function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk2h68td.aspx), but it's part of the POSIX API and may not work well with standard Windows I/O.

Comment: I would modify that slightly - it may be acceptable to close stdout if you have a specific reason for doing so, i.e., you need to signal the end of the data without actually exiting.  Of course you would have to be careful to make sure the program doesn't ever use stdout after doing so.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: It may be reasonable in some specialized circumstances, but you would need to carefully evaluate any libraries or other code you may be using.  For example, on some systems you may get output when a process dies via a signal ("Terminated", "Killed", "Segmentation Fault", etc.), and I'm not sure if that requires a functional stdout/stderr, or how it behaves if there is no stdout.

Comment: you can close and then re-open the 3 std handles with /dev/null, so that 0, 1, 2, routes to null, just like how we daemonize a process.

Comment: @Calvin: There is no reason to do that on Unix (because [`dup2(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) does all that for you), and I'm not sure it works on Windows.

Comment: Signals shouldn't be a problem on Windows, provided you don't register any signal handlers they're disabled by default.  But you would certainly have to be careful about third-party libraries.

Comment: Mention explicitly that it is ok to use `.communicate()` even if the child application code does not close stdout explicitly. I would flush stdout explicitly if it makes sense for a given application to handle write errors to stdout (it doesn't for most applications).

Comment: I don't agree with this.  Closing stdout is not just something for specialized cases.  I would argue that every program *must* close stdout to verify that it closes cleanly.  At the very least, if `fclose(stdout)` fails, an error message should be written to stderr. Practically, it is probably sufficient to check the error status by invoking `fflush`, but calling `fclose` would be more appropriate.  If you're worried about atexit handlers, register a function that closes fopen before any other exit functions are registered.