# How to use fgets() function so that it only reads 12 characters per line?

Tags: c, function, fgets

I have a file that contains the following words:

```
Theendsherethiswillnotjaksdjlasdfjkl;asdjfklasdjfkl;asdfjl;
these
are
the
```

Below is my code :

```
int i = 0;
    bool duplicateFound = false;
        while(fgets(line,12,fp)){
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                if (strcmp(wordList[j], line) == 0){
                    duplicateFound = true;
                    printf("Duplicate Found on Line %d : %s\n", j, wordList[j]);
                }
            }
            if (duplicateFound == false){
                strcpy(wordList[i], line);
                printf("%s", wordList[i]);
            }
            i++;*/

            printf("%s", line);
        }
```

I am using line to save each word so that I can later check it for duplicates in the array. 
I want it so that the function only reads up to 12 characters on each line but it outputs the following output.

ACTUAL OUTPUT :

```
Theendsherethiswillnotjaksdjlasdfjkl;asdjfklasdjfkl;asdfjl;
these
are
the
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Theendsheret
these
are
the
```

Comment: Best to post compilable code.

Comment: What's wrong with `fgets(line, sizeof line, fp); line[12] = '\0'`?

Comment: If you want to read up to 12 chars with fgets then you must use 13 as the length of the buffer (remember you have to leave space for the '\0' at the end of the string. If you want to ignore chars after the 12 one on a line, then you also need to check for a '\n' in the buffer. If you don't see it then you need to read and skip chars until you read the end of the line or the end of the file.

Comment: Is there an easy way to discard other characters after 12?

Comment: @WilliamPursell will that discard the characters after that and move to the next line?

Comment: @NeelPatel You need to verify that `fgets` read a newline.  It will effectively discard characters after the 12th, since all standard string functions will ignore that data after the null terminator.  It will not "move to the next line".  Your loop will do that with the next fgets.  If the line of input was larger than your buffer (eg, `line` does not contain a newline), just loop on getchar until you see a newline.  (This makes the logic complex, since you also need to check for EOF while looping on getchar, or you can just abort if you have malformed input with long lines.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell can you show me how i would right that? I have provides my code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should just call fgets and then do `line[12] = '\0'`, but that doesn't cleanly deal with input that has long lines.  One option is to simply abort if fgets ever returns a partial line (eg, if `strchr(line, '\n')` returns NULL). 
 If you want to handle long lines, you can just discard data with getchar until you see a newline.  Assuming that you don't want to consider the newline to be one of the 12 characters, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
        char line[13];
        while( fgets(line, 13, stdin) ) {
                char *c = strchr(line, '\n');
                int ch;
                if( c == NULL ) while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF ) {
                        if( ch == '\n' ) {
                                break;
                        }
                } else {
                        *c = '\0';
                }
                if( printf("%s\n", line) < 0 ) {
                        break;
                }
        }
        return ferror(stdout) || ferror(stdin) || fclose(stdout) || fclose(stdin);
}
```

Comment: So would I be able to save “line” in my wordlist array?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with the data.  Saving it to the wordlist array is certainly one possibility.

Comment: So where would I put the statement wordList[i] = line?

Comment: You still need to use `strcpy` . `line` is going to get overwritten on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Where would i put that statement though? Would be underneath the printf statement?

Comment: The code you've posted is incomplete, and does not even include a declaration of wordList.  I expect you would replace the printf with something suitable.

Comment: `fclose(stdout) || ferror(stdout) || ferror(stdin)` is interesting.  When `fclose()` fails as "Whether or not the call succeeds, the stream is disassociated from the file" and subsequent use of `ferror(stdout)` is UB.

Comment: @chux . Good point.  There really needs to be a clean, idomatic way to validate streams on exit.

Comment: @NeelPatel You need to be more specific in your description of the error you are having.  If you post complete code, it is probably extremely trivial to incorporate my answer into your code to do what you want.  Until you post complete code, any attempt to debug your code is doomed to failure.

Comment: @WilliamPursell are you sure you need to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32014383/2472827

Comment: I would argue that it is desirable.  It is necessary to check all writes to prevent a process which has inherited a signal disposition to ignore SIGPIPE from failing to terminate on a write failure, and I think that's more of an issue than ill-behaved atexit handlers trying to write to stdout.  However, it is probably sufficient to check status returned by `printf`, et al rather than checking return status of `fclose`.